# CakePHP basic auth on API (json) request

Tags: json, cakephp

I want to make a request to `resource/index.json`, but since I `index` is not allowed without authentication it redirects me to login page. That's the behavior I want when no username:password has been sent

The thing is how do I set `AuthComponent` to work with both `Form` and `Basic` and only check for basic when the request goes through `api` prefix.

Also, does it automatically authenticate when found username and password in the header or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use **Friend's of Cake** `TokenAuthenticate`, and yes, it works along with `FormAuthenticate` so I am able to use both.

As a matter of fact, it automatically chooses the component it's going to use based on if there is an existing `_token` param or a `X-MyApiTokenHeader` header.

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form',
            'Authenticate.Token' => array(
                'parameter' => '_token',
                'header' => 'X-MyApiTokenHeader',
                'userModel' => 'User',
                'scope' => array('User.active' => 1),
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'token' => 'public_key',
                ),
                'continue' => true
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

in respective controller add few lines

```
class NameController extends AppController {
    public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Auth->allow("index");
        }
}
```

This will allow index without authentication.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco may be i just not able to understand your scenario.

Comment: My question was "does it automatically authenticate when found username and password in the header or do I have to do it manually?"